# Set same ID for records having same set of field values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following data where I need to get records with the same ACTION, PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID, and TYPE and set the ID for those records using the least ID.
In case below, transactions 1456014, 1456016, 1456018, and 1456019 has the same set of ACTION, PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID and TYPE.  So I need to set the ID of those 4 records to 12851 which is the least among those 4.

```
TXN_ID      ACTION  ID      PARENT_ID       CHILD_ID    TYPE
1456014     CREATED 12851   653022          370023      Acquisition
1456016     CREATED 12852   653022          370023      Acquisition
1456018     CREATED 12853   653022          370023      Acquisition
1456019     CREATED 12854   653022          370023      Acquisition
1456013     CREATED 12855   653020          370023      Acquisition
1456012     CREATED 12856   653022          370024      Acquisition
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you're asking

```
UPDATE table_name dest
   SET dest.id = (SELECT MIN(src.id)
                    FROM table_name src
                   WHERE src.action    = dest.action
                     AND src.parent_id = dest.parent_id
                     AND src.child_id  = dest.child_id
                     AND src.type      = dest.type)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM table_name src
                WHERE src.action    = dest.action
                  AND src.parent_id = dest.parent_id
                  AND src.child_id  = dest.child_id
                  AND src.type      = dest.type
                  AND src.id       != dest.id );
```

If most of your data is going to be updated, you may want to eliminate the `EXISTS` clause and just update every row (incurring the cost of a few meaningless updates) rather than incurring the cost of doing the `EXISTS`.

Taking a step back, though, the fact that you want to do this in the first place implies that you have a normalization problem with the table.  If `id` depends on `action`, `type`, `child_id`, and `parent_id`, and those four attributes are not at least a unique key, that implies that those attributes probably need to get factored out in your data model.

Comment: Good, exhaustive answer, but small correction is needed in lines 5 and  11. You have `AND src.parent_id = src.parent_id` and should be `AND src.parent_id = dest.parent_id`. Current version updated transaction 1456013 and this has no counterpart.